# Sufficient to only install security updates on Debian?

Tags: updates, debian

On my Debian, I only do security updates:

`deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main`

`deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main`

For example, Debian recently migrated from 10.3 to 10.4, but I still use version 10.3 and automatically install available security updates.

Is that enough for security?

Answer (score 1):

That should be enough, until they announce that the version is so old that it won't be supported anymore (at which point they'll stop providing security updates). Since this is one of the newest releases, you should be fine, at least until 2022 if [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Release_table) is accurate.

Think of it this way: if it *wouldn't* be enough for security, why would they continue to provide security updates?

Of course, just installing security updates doesn't prevent you from making your system insecure by other settings (weak passwords etc.), but in that regard there is no difference between 10.3 and 10.4.

Comment: I will quote one member: _No, it’s not enough for security: in the run-up to a point-release, some upgrades which include security fixes (notably, the kernel) are pushed to the main repository as part of the point-release, not to the security repository._